# Can a "peer" component respond to an event from another "peer" component

Tags: angular

Let's say I have three Angular 2 components: A, B and C.  A is the parent "container" for both B (View) and C (Add).  Can C emit an event that is caught and responded to by B - or can only A catch and respond to events from C (and B).

```
   A
  / \
 B   C   <-- throws event, we want B to respond to the event.
```

As far as I can tell, events can only bubble up to the Parent, A (I have this working already).  I'm trying to avoid have A reroute the event back down to B.

Is this even possible?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it at this ways:

- Create a service to share informations across components;
- Using A as intermediate, @ViewChild;
- Use events, I prefer this because decouples the code;
- Use observables to chain events automatically to other components, I also prefer this one;

Comment: But the event can't go from C to B directly?  It would have to be brokered through A...my understanding. I haven't seen anything that works with events where C throws the event and B catches it directly.

Comment: Using services and events simultaneously you can. Providing a service that register an event or obervable could help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- pass event to the parent and then to the child (as you mentioned)
- create a service to communicate between components

Choosing the right one depends on your particular case.